# How to detect camera plug/unplug when running on Raspberry (Qt)?

Tags: qt, camera, qml, raspberry-pi3

I have an issue as below.

I build qt app with qtmultimedia to capture video from a camera on Raspberry pi 3 and show to screen. 
When the camera module is working well, if I remove it, I want to show on screen "Camera is disconnected". 
I tried these solutions but it doesn't work correctly. [Detect webcam is unplugged](https://forum.qt.io/topic/77694/detect-when-webcam-is-unplugged)

Do you have any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: why not use `QFileSystemWatcher` to watch  device path `/dev/cam0` of your CAM ???

Comment: @Redanium. I tried it. But when removing the camera from the bus, I still received  /dev/cam0.

Answer (score 1):

### Suitable for hot-pluggable devices (USB, IEEE1394, ... etc)

There is a user-made class called [QDeviceWatcher](https://github.com/wang-bin/qdevicewatcher) which I didn't try and here is the forum post [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/9382/qdevicewatcher-make-hotplug-detection-easy)

Comment: Thanks, @Redanium. But I think it will not work. Because the camera module is plugged to Raspberry via CSI bus.

Comment: @Shymaxtic Hmmm . take a look [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=68247)

Comment: Thanks for your support @Redanium. But I still cannot resolve this problem. Because when running the camera. There is file "/dev/video0", but then if I unplug the camera, the file "/dev/video0" still exists.

Comment: @Shymaxtic **FYI** **MIPI CSI** is not **hot-pluggable**, and what is the output of your app when you disconnect the camera while it's showing ???

Comment: My app will detect camera unplugged and show a widget with a warning message "Camera is disconnected".

Comment: @Shymaxtic what is the output of your app ? not what you want it to output

Comment: @Shymaxtic I think by **unplugging** the ***CSI cable*** your **media player** will emit an [QMediaPlayer::Error](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qmediaplayer.html#Error-enum) signal which you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can Monitor the camera states by inspecting on below camera handler functions.
When you physically connect/Disconnect the camera status will be changed and this handler is called.
`onCameraStateChanged:{
if(availability === Camera.Unavailable || availability ===
Camera.ResourceMissing)
{
console.log("Camera is unavailable)");
}

```
           if(availability === Camera.available)
           {
                 console.log("Camera is available)");
           }`
```